# TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable int object in Django rest framework

Tags: django, api, object, django-rest-framework, iterable

I am trying to get a list of orders of only those products associated with that merchant. In my project, every product is associated with a merchant. In the merchant dashboard, merchants should be able to view only their products and orders.

When I try to filter the orders based on products associated with that merchant, I got the above error.

My models:

```
class Product(models.Model):  
    
    merchant = models.ForeignKey(Seller,on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank=True,null=True)
    category = models.ManyToManyField(Category, blank=False)
    brand = models.ForeignKey(Brand, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Order(models.Model):
    ORDER_STATUS = (
        ('To_Ship', 'To Ship',),
        ('Shipped', 'Shipped',),
        ('Delivered', 'Delivered',),
        ('Cancelled', 'Cancelled',),
    )
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True)
    #items = models.ManyToManyField(OrderItem,blank=True, null=True,related_name="order_items")
    #start_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    order_status = models.CharField(max_length=50,choices=ORDER_STATUS,default='To_Ship')

    ordered_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    ordered = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    total_price = models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=True,null=True)
    #billing_details = models.OneToOneField('BillingDetails',on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True,blank=True,related_name="order")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.email

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Orders"
        ordering = ('-id',)

class OrderItem(models.Model):
    #user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True)
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order,on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True,null=True,related_name='order_items')
    item = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank=True, null=True)
    order_variants = models.ForeignKey(Variants,on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank=True,null=True)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    total_item_price = models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=True,null=True)


    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.quantity} items of {self.item} of {self.order.user}"

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural= "Cart Items"
        ordering = ('-id',)
```

My views:

```
class SellerOrderAPIView(ListAPIView):
    permission_classes = [AllowAny]
    serializer_class = OrderItemSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        merchant = get_object_or_404(Seller,self.kwargs['pk'])
        return OrderItem.objects.all(item__merchant=merchant)
```

My serializers:

```
class OrderItemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    order_variants = VariantSerializer(read_only=True)
    #order_variants =VariantSerializer()
    item = ProductSerializer(read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = OrderItem
        fields = ['id','order','item','order_variants', 'quantity']
        # depth = 1
```

[image]

Here, I saw that when I see the orderdetails, merhchant is inside item, that's why I tried filtering the queryset using item__merchant=merchant, but I got this error.

My urls:

```
path('api/merchantorder/<int:pk>', views.SellerOrderAPIView.as_view(), name='api-merchant-orderdetail'),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify the name of the field on which you filter:

```
class SellerOrderAPIView(ListAPIView):
    permission_classes = [AllowAny]
    serializer_class = OrderItemSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        merchant = get_object_or_404(Seller, pk=self.kwargs['pk'])
        return OrderItem.objects.filter(item__merchant=merchant)
```

you can however simply avoid the lookup and work with:

```
class SellerOrderAPIView(ListAPIView):
    permission_classes = [AllowAny]
    serializer_class = OrderItemSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        return OrderItem.objects.filter(item__merchant=self.kwargs['pk'])
```

Comment: Can you tell me what is the difference between the above two?? I have always used the first one.

Comment: @SarojPaudel: you do not fetch the `Seller`. Django will simply make a JOIN. The only difference is that if the `Seller` does not exists, then in the first view it will return a 404 whereas for the second it will return an empty list.

Comment: ok last question. What is this JOIN means? Also I am fetching Seller, I am trying to get the object of seller based on that pk.

Comment: @SarojPaudel: it will make a JOIN on the database: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp